# Underline errors in NEW files with #define not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, underline

I'm having problems with the visual studio 2010 editor. Since today, visual studio won't underline errors any more if I use `#define` like so:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
class foo{
blabla
}
#endif
```

If i remove the defining commands, the errors show up.

The weird thing is, I have other files in my project with the exact same setup and error underlining works just fine in those but not the new files that I'm creating?

I have tried resetting settings and re-installing but none of it helps.

I have also tried doing this in other projects and I have the same issue.

Just wondering if anyone had a similar issue and can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this isn't an exact science, and I've seen/experienced it before. In my case, dumping the intellisense database fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however this doesnt seem to fix my problem.
I also want to note that if i change the #define to anything except the #ifndef name, the errors are underlined again.